# Getting Values from Joined Tables on Views

Tags: join, view, acumatica

I am trying to get a value from a joined field on a view. Example code:

```
  public PXSelectJoin<Table1, 
     LeftJoinSingleTable<Table2, On<Table2.FieldA, Equal<Table1.FieldB>>>> Document
```

Now say that Table2 has FieldC that is not contained within Table 1. How would I get that data?

Example:

```
public SomeFunction()
{
   if (Table2.FieldC != null)
   {
      //do something
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eric, have you checked **Accessing the Retrieved Data Records** section from the T200 training course?
[image]

Usually one joins several DACs in primary data view to either use them in Where clause or show (in read-only mode) joined DAC fields in UI.

Besides what's shown in T200 class, 2 options are available to access fields of a DAC joined within primary data view:

1. execute BQL query with main DAC matching the one you originally joined in primary data view:

   ```
   var joinedDAC = PXSelect<Table2, Where<Table2.FieldA, Equal<Current<Table1.FieldB>>>>>.Select(this);
   ```
2. in case you need to update some values in a joined DAC and save them back to database, it's necessary to declare a data view with main DAC matching the one you originally joined in primary data view:

   ```
   PXSelect<Table2, Where<Table2.FieldA, Equal<Current<Table1.FieldB>>>>> JoinedDAC;
   ```

   To access fields of a joined DAC simply invoke Select method for the JoinedDAC day view:

   ```
   Table2 record = JoinedDAC.Select();
   ```

On a side note, ARDocType is just a string field declared in the SOOrder DAC:

```
public partial class SOOrder : PX.Data.IBqlTable, PX.Data.EP.IAssign, IFreightBase, ICCAuthorizePayment, ICCCapturePayment, IInvoice
{
    ...

    #region ARDocType
    public abstract class aRDocType : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected String _ARDocType;
    [PXString(ARRegister.docType.Length, IsFixed = true)]
    [PXFormula(typeof(Selector<SOOrder.orderType, SOOrderType.aRDocType>))]
    public virtual String ARDocType
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ARDocType;
        }
        set
        {
            this._ARDocType = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    ...
}
```

And `Document.Current` will always return an instance of the SOOrder DAC as internally it invokes `Document.Cache.Current` also always returning current record from the cache. PXCache is designed to work only with records of a single type and cannot include any joined records. ResultSets containing all joined DACs are stored in the PXView QueryCache...

Comment: Does this mean I cannot grab those fields from a predefined view as I have defined above? 

I was looking over the source code and saw that an object in the SOOrder DAC exists for ARDocType, but ARDocType doesn't exist in the SQL Table SOOrder. The way it is accessed is using Document.Current.ARDocType. I was wondering if I could do something along those lines for what I'm trying to accomplish as well.

Comment: I looked over your solutions and that shoudl do what I need to do. Thanks again Ruslan!